# Slideshow right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I saw this question in this link visit it to see what I mean: [slide right to left](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/0suk5v3t/4/) - this is like my problem but I want do this with click not Automatic.

I mean pull the next item. I hope you understand what I mean. I used google translate.because I don't know English very well. Thank you

---

These are my codes:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="more-inf-items ">
                        <div class="body-find-more-img">
                            <img src="../../Images/conferenceImage.png" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="body-find-more-titile">
                                <h3>Confrance</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="body-find-more-decoration">
                                <blockquote>
                                    Browsers generally render blockquote text as indented text. If your
                                    quoted text needs to display within a non-quoted paragraph, you should use the
                                    Browsers generally render blockquote text as indented text. If your
                                    quoted text needs to display within a non-quoted paragraph, you should use the
                                    Browsers generally render blockquote text as indented text. If your

                                </blockquote>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="more-inf-items ">
                        <div class="body-find-more-img">
                            <img src="../../Images/how-get-girl-interested-men-facts.png" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="body-find-more-titile">
                                <h3>Dating</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="body-find-more-decoration">
                                <blockquote>
                                    Browsers generally render blockquote text as indented text. If your
                                    quoted text needs to display within a non-quoted paragraph, you should use the
                                    Browsers generally render blockquote text as indented text. If your
                                    quoted text needs to display within a non-quoted paragraph, you should use the

                                </blockquote>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="more-inf-items">
                        <div class="body-find-more-img">
                            <img src="../../Images/preview.png" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="body-find-more-titile">
                                <h3>Dating</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="body-find-more-decoration">
                                <blockquote>
                                    Browsers generally render blockquote text as indented text. If your
                                    quoted text needs to display within a non-quoted paragraph, you should use the
                                    Browsers generally render blockquote text as indented text. If your
                                    quoted text needs to display within a non-quoted paragraph, you should use the
                                    Browsers generally render blockquote text as indented text. If your

                                </blockquote>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

---

In my codes there are 3 items that I want to do [this action](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/0suk5v3t/4/) with, but with clicking.

Answer (score 0):

From the code in JSFiddle, `setInterval(cycle, delay);` is the code which triggers the action.

> **setInterval(function, milliseconds, param1, param2, ...)**
>
> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression
>   at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

Therefore, instead of letting the action to be called every interval, you can replace the `setInterval(...)` with `$('.container').click(cycle);` to let `cycle()` be called when `$('.container')` is clicked.

> **JQuery .click(handler)**
>
> Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event,
>   or trigger that event on an element.